# Concatenat ct and xray image

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a project final about fusion the ct images and cray images in CNN covid_19
How can I do the concatenate between the two model .?
And how I do the concatenate in the final (training and testing).?

Comment: can you please be clear with your question. From what I understand, if you are trying to concatenate two inputs, you can look at this example (https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/3D_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=udONME5Uo5lR). Please provide a clear explanation with colab or code, so I can take a look at it. Thanks!